# jQuery return data to sibling in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, I have a anchor that has a text value. I'm using jQuery to execute a function when someone clicks on the anchor tag. 
The function is a post request to a script that returns a value.

Currently I can pass the value to the script, and return the data back to the text of a tag. div, span, etc.

However, what I am having trouble with is correctly setting the text of a sibling of the clicked anchor tag.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<tr class='row'>
  <td><a href='#">another value</a></td>
  <td class='mh'><a href='#'>valueforscript</a></td>
  <td class='results'></td>
</tr>
<div id='testdiv'>testdiv</div>
```

The jQuery that I have tried is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.mh a").click(function(){
      var mhtext = $(this).text();
      $.post('qt.php', {mhpost: mhtext}, function(data){
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings(".results").text(data);    
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I can make this work by using a selector directly like this:

```
$("#testdiv").text(data);
```

But for what I am working on, I really need to be able to use this function to set the text value of:

```
<td class='results'></td>
```

Just not sure how to access this with parents and siblings. I have tried to use this selection syntax without any results..

```
$(this).closest("tr").siblings(".results").text(data);
```

UPDATE:
Wanted to add some code, but comment area is kinda small.

I have tried using:

```
parent() instead of closest()
```

This did not work, but I think the problem is a bit deeper.
@budhajeewa's answer is correct in a basic example as seen here on jsfiddle : qv5sgxf3/3/.

This, however won't work in my code. 
A little more detail. The table that I am trying to manipulate is returned from php. So, the JQuery is acting on returned PHP code. 
I can see this could cause a problem with DOM if I was calling an external script with onload, but the table in this case is fully loaded as the jQuery is being applied to a click.

To test the my Jfiddle code in site code qv5sgxf3/3/, I placed it in, and added a test div to also return the data to.
I also removed the post code, just in case there was a chance any delay in the post would cause a problem. This works in JFiddle with static values.

Now my jQuery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td.mh a").click(function(){
    var mhtext = $(this).text();
    <!-- what I want to work like in the jfiddle link -->                     
    $(this).parent("td").siblings(".results").text(mhtext);

    <!-- What does work -->
    $("#testdiv").text(mhtext);

    <!-- what also doesnt work. -->
    $("td.results").text(mhtext);
  });
});
</script>
```

Again, the html the jQuery is modifying is returned from PHP:

```
<tr class='row'>
  <td><a href='#">another value</a></td>
  <td class='mh'><a href='#'>valueforscript</a></td>
  <td class='results'></td>
</tr>
<div id='testdiv'>testdiv</div>
```

However, as you can see from the comments in the jQuery, the parent.sibling jQuery selection works in jsfiddle, but not for me. However, placing the value in a div outside of my table works fine.

This also works when adding the post code to my php script the the onclick function. Just not with the parent.sibling td, where I want to place my data.

Answer (score 2):

Try `parent()` instead of `closest()`.

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.results').text(data);
```

Comment: `Thanks for the advise, however still doesn't work. The <td class='results'></td> is never populated using either closest or parent.

Comment: @luskbo: Try doing it without the HTTP request, i.e., try to modify the content of the TD directly on click event.